# How to send a message to a bounty giver?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Someone added a bounty to an old question. They are not the OP. I want to ask them for more details about what they are looking for. Is there a way to direct a comment to them so they get a notification? If not, would this be a good feature request?

The above-mentioned question already has answers that completely (in my opinion) satisfy the problem and the bounty giver just selected one of the preset reasons (i.e. looking for credible sources...). So I have no idea what they want.

Comment: hmm... i'm not sure. If the user has commented/close voted on the post, an @user would notify them. i don't know if attaching a bounty to the question has the same effect.

Comment: Based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments) that should be possible.

Comment: @rene Oh ok. I was unsure because their name didn't autocomplete after I typed `@` and the first few characters of their name (as the answer in that question noted).

Comment: Sort of related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345774/introduce-autocompletion-for-every-pingable-user) question about adding all pingable users to the autocomplete. I would add bounty givers to the list of names that should show up in the autocomplete.

Comment: It's also mentioned in [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) that @user works for bounty givers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can ping the Bounty giver as demo-ed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194534/dc-js-access-data-points-in-multiple-charts-when-click-datapoint-in-first-chart)

[image: screen shot of a bounty, set by user rene, and an @ping to that user by NobadyNada]

That comment pinged me and showed up in my inbox. Jeff explained [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments) that users that show up in the revision history are pingable. That excludes most close voters because only a single user that is bound to an event in the history of a post will be pingable. Notice that their names in that case will **not** autocomplete when typing the comment.

Comment: Thanks for testing that.

Comment: You just happened to ask your question at the right time ;)

Comment: "That excludes most close voters..." - Is that right? I always thought any user whose name shows in a close banner is pingable.

Comment: Only gold dupe hamers. @mike

Comment: Oh, jeez, no kiddin'? Why did I think otherwise? I've misinformed a coupla users, then. Guess I've gotta go search my comments. Well, good to know now, at least.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm pretty sure I'm not kidding this time otherwise I would have had much more pings in my inbox if this was possible.