# Introduce Autocompletion for every pingable user

Tags: feature-request, comments

Inspired by [rene's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345749/2441442):

> Jeff explained [on
>   MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129232/are-bounty-placers-notified-of-comments)
>   that users that show up in the revision history are pingable. That
>   excludes most close voters because only a single user that is bound to
>   an event in the history of a post will be pingable. Notice that their
>   names in that case will **not** autocomplete when typing the comment.

I feel wrong, that we have no autocompletion for every pingable name, when typing a comment.

So my request: Introduce Autocompletion whenever a ping is possible.

This also helps in self documentation by User Experience.

Comment: One thing to consider (ignoring any implementation issues) is that it might confuse users who are trying to participate just in commenting and don't wish to address a reviewer, an editor or a binding close voter etc... Having names pop up that aren't in the user's "line of sight" as it were might be confusing or even lead to wrong pinging.

Comment: @JonClements agree. Maybe some super fancy fontawesome icon (or any other indicator) behind the name, which shows how this person is involved to the post, would help.

Comment: @JonClements Most new users don't even realise you can ping people anyway!

Comment: Maybe some kind of specific extended-autocomplete command to bring up the whole list? I don't know what kind of input would be appropriate to bring up an extended list.

Comment: The OP / answerer will be notified automatically without ping. And for other commentators, the auto complete is there.

Comment: Whats your definition of a *"pingable name"*?

Comment: How would this type of autocomplete work? User name are not (as far as I know) unique. So would need some way to distinguish the `Fred` from Monaco from the `Fred` from Canberra from the many `Fred`s in the USA.

Comment: @SagarV, nobody is talking about other commentators.

Comment: @AdrianHHH, the same way it current works

Comment: @Liam Somebody I can ping via `@notation`. Not sure what you mean with your last 2 comments.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Go to [Users](http://stackoverflow.com/users) and start typing "newb"...Loads and loads of users use that username or something similar. So if your thinking, the whole userbase this will be very impractical. Hence, what exactly is your definition of a pingable user. The whole userbase? Someone who's participated in the question somehow (how exactly?), some other definition?

Comment: Read the quote from rene's answer @Liam

Comment: @Liam All users, except most close voters, listed in the revision history of a post, are pingable. Some of these users currently do not appear in the auto-completion list. OP is asking to add all these people to the auto-completion list.

Comment: @AdrianHHH that's an issue now surely? Regardless of how many pop up if two Freds commented how would you distinguish between them? That's interesting.

Comment: I was just going to write up a feature request and then I found that you had already made it. Upvote.

Comment: @JonClements this seems like a minimal risk. Personally I was under the impression for a while that I couldn't ping close voters because of lack of autocomplete. Autocomplete also prevents typos which could mean failing to notify a user while thinking that you have.

Comment: I've been here for over eight years and only just learned that you can ping people other than those that autocomplete.

Comment: I'd also be happy with some button to directly @ mention a question voter. Some people have names I don't have on my keyboard, so it's not very easy to even write those. Then you might have somebody who has an unexpected character somewhere in the middle of their name. Case in point, my username was previously all lowercase and some people would reply to me with `@viaz` because they assumed the lowercase **L** is an uppercase **i**. So, I changed the name to make the distinction. But somebody might even use a Cyrillic "е" in their name and so typing "us**e**rname" would fail to ping them.