# How to contact the editor of a post for clarification?

Tags: support, edits, notifications, comment-replies

I came across an edit that I'm fairly sure is incorrect, but want to confirm with the editor first before I roll it back. Is there a way I can contact the editor to get clarification?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can `@`-mention any user that has successfully edited a post in a comment on that post. Their name will not show up in the autocomplete box when typing, but they *will* be notified.

See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) on Meta.SE for more information.

Comment: Feature request: Auto complete *everyone* that can be notified (e.g.  editors, hammer closers, moderators, etc.)

Comment: @user000001 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345774/introduce-autocompletion-for-every-pingable-user

Comment: @user000001: I think it should work at least for post editors, as it is not currently working.

Comment: Feature request: Allow the pinging of users whose suggested edits have been rejected.

Comment: @Siguza That feature [has been requested on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198977/allow-failed-editors-be-replied-to).

Comment: @Siguza: I think it should be all editors.

Comment: @sergiol yeah, same thing. I'm pretty sure those are the only ones missing.

Comment: @Siguza: No. The one post that I was trying to notify the editor, his/her edit was not been rejected.

Comment: @sergiol: that fixes your problem but Siguza is trying to fix the problem more generally.

Comment: @sergiol Then AFAIK even though their name wasn't autocompleted, they would've been notified by a ping. But I think I found another group that cannot be pinged: Editors whose edits are still up for review.

Comment: Personally, I don't think there *is* a problem, but if you think so would you mind discussing it in the feature request rather than the comments here?