# How to communicate with an editor in case of you not agreeing with an edit?

Tags: support, edits

I am obviously going to leave it as it is a good edit in the end. However, it seems odd for someone to basically re-write the whole answer.

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34919582/3

Is there no way to comment, or chat to the editor if you don't agree with their edit?

Comment: Wow, that is way more substantive that we would expect edits to be. Feel flee to revert if you don't feel this is your answer anymore. That should probably have been posted as a *new* answer. You can contact editors in a comment on your post by tagging them with `@name`, see [How do comment @replies work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Comment: I've rolled that back, that's really a new answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters why are you rollbacking something that the OP accepted "**I am obviously going to leave it as it is a good edit in the end**"

Comment: @Braiam because it is entirely rewritten by someone else adding a lot of information. It would no longer be the OP's work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's desition **of the author**, you shouldn't override the author. He's is the author. **Respect the author**.

Comment: Just decide if it's a good edit that improved the post. If it is keep it. If it isn't roll it back. There's no need for other people to make that decision for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters FWIW Your rollback was rolled back.

Comment: Although it certainly is "really a new answer," it seems more beneficial to the community as a whole to let it stand, given that the original author approves of the changes (which seems to be the case).

Comment: @AndyHayden actually, OP wishes were reinstated.

Comment: @Azar how exactly is a new answer? Did you read the previous one and the edited? Both of them are saying exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Braiam: no, now *you* made the decision for the author. What was this about **respecting the author** when you don't have community consensus on this in the first place? **At the very least wait until this discussion is concluded**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That could be applied to your rollback too. Frankly I don't see any need for any third party to roll it back the author can if they don't like it.

Comment: @MartinSmith: we've been over that a few times now. Perhaps it does. I do take issue with Briaim then doing the exact same thing I'm being accused of while we are still discussing this.

Comment: I did certainly see it as a new answer since he went into way more detail. If you going to replace the majority of the original it just seems like it should be a new answer... even if conceptually the same.

I wanted to meantion this to the editor. 

I don't use StackOverflow for rep... but to help people so I think the argument of me gaining rep is moot. As long as the community benefits.

Comment: On a separate point, I think it should be my decision to rollback the revision or not. I've left it for a reason, could we please leave it that way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how about you drop this and instead follow Shog advice: **communicate with the author**. You have made no attempt to do it before nor after the edit, and keep pushing your point of view. I was waiting for you to actually try to ping Oliver and ask him, instead you pinged *me* to complain....

Comment: @Braiam: ahem: [How to communicate with an editor in case of you not agreeing with an edit?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/471324).

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's not communicating. That's unilaterally expressing what you did without resource to disagreeing. Do you really  feel that you are asking for input? This is how communicating works: Oliver, I see an extensive edit done by Beau, do you agree with it? You can roll back it if you desire as described in <link>. <- Communication asking for input. If you want to communicate, it shouldn't read as a memo. (btw, the answer is in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348873/#comment471458_348873)).

Comment: @Oliver: thanks for the clarity on this.

Comment: I'm disappointed. Wrong is wrong, are we now going to allow the hijacker to learn the lesson that they can keep trying to do this to other answers? This kind of behavior needs to be nipped in the bud, IMO.

Comment: @gimby. It isn't wrong to make extensive improvements to an answer. If the editor is happy to selflessly forgo the rep for the edit and the post author to accept the edit there is no problem.

Comment: @Oliver: In general it is not practical for users to leave rollbacks solely to the domain of post authors. Some authors are not aware of the ability; others are not even active (or only at intervals); still others have a very poor grasp of what is or isn't appropriate on SO. So it's not reasonable to expect an editor with 2k rep and the privilege of rolling back edits to magically know that you have simply refrained from rolling back an edit that would normally qualify as bad. Instead, just rollback the rollback if it happens, problem solved.

Comment: @MartinSmith sure, but the context here is near complete replacement. That as said is when you post a new answer, to be judged on its own merit.

Comment: @MartinSmith: _"It isn't wrong to make extensive improvements to an answer"_ Actually that is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @Oliver - Sorry to cause any stress. Glad that you understood my intentions.

Comment: Am I the only person to think that Martijn's original rollback was justified?  This is no longer Oliver's answer.  The right thing to do would have been (1) copy Beau's new revision to a new answer, acknowledging Beau as the author, and with "Community Wiki" switched on; (2) rollback Oliver's answer to the original.  That way, both answers get to benefit the community, and nobody benefits unfairly from Beau's work.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I don't know that outside opinions matter much given that both the editor and the OP seem to have reached an understanding.

Comment: @BeauSmith no worries man :) It's chilled I was curious, and seemed to have opened a can of worms :P

Comment: Comments are not for discussion.... Lol

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can ping the editor in a comment under the post (though his name will not auto-complete).

If you disagree with an edit on your answer, you can also roll it back to previous revision, from the link the revision history:

[image]

If two people disagree on the state of a question, there is a "rollback war", and a moderator is automatically notified. Note however that rollback wars are not always resolved in favor of the author.

Comment: I would like you to expand your answer in the case of no disagreement of the edit, ie. the what the title is asking. I can rewrite this whole answer by simply shifting paragraphs around and would still be the same answer.

Comment: @Braiam if there's no disagreement about the edit, then everyone agrees what should happen... No? But the title is asking 'in case of *not* agreeing'. Also, I am not sure why you want to rewrite my answer...

Comment: I was using an example. Since shifting paragraphs would be seen as "rewriting" the post, as it would show lots of red/green yet the message would be intact.

Comment: @Braiam oh I see. I'm more in favor of adding a new answer instead of edits that totally rewrite an existing answer. Having said that, as a third party, I wouldn't roll back such an edit if it was superior than the original. If the OP wants he can roll it back by himself. He even gets a notification for major edits on his posts.

Comment: Thank you, the auto-complete was want confused me, as I expected it to work.

The advise is sound and so marking as answer. For this particular edit it will stay as is but now I know the strategy in future.

Comment: Feature request: [Introduce Autocompletion for every pingable user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345774/introduce-autocompletion-for-every-pingable-user)

Comment: @Suragch: It's a bit ironic that [I had made the exact same comment somewhere else](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346402/how-to-contact-the-editor-of-a-post-for-clarification/346403#comment461876_346403) :)

Answer (score 5):

@user000001's answer is excellent; I'd just like to add one other thing, and that is that in the case that the author of the edit had less than 2k, the edit had to go through the review queue.  Stack Overflow has implemented [a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/333472) that allows the author of the post to re-review that suggested edit.

That is to say, if a low-rep user like me edits your post and the edit gets approved (in spite of the fact that it made massive changes), you can change the status of that edit to *rejected* (I believe the link to the suggested edit goes into your inbox), provided that the post has not been edited since.

As per comments, it works the other way around as well.  If the edit has been *rejected* by the review queue, you can also re-review it to *approve*.

That said, I agreed with everything @user000001 said as well.

Comment: Do you know that the feature is actually aimed to those that feel that the edits should have been approved?

Comment: @Braiam, sure, but it works either way, so I've included for reference.

Comment: Then why are you only poiting out the rejection part? Are you aware that in this case the author was explicitly in favor of this edit? If you are going to advertise something, doing throughly! Include both sides!

Comment: @Braiam, thanks for pointing out; I've edited.

Answer (score -15):

You can comment using @editor to communicate with the editor if necessary but I don't feel that it is at all. If was a good edit, you will benefiting of it. It obviously doesn't change the main point of your answer:

> since you use 2fa, you need a Personal Access Token.

The edit just expanded the answer in the same vein without changing at all the meaning: it still explains why it happens and how to fix it. The only thing added was an example of sorts.

I were you, I would leave it as is. It is a leap improvement of the content and in the long run, **you and others will be benefiting from it.**

---

Just for fun I opened the timeline, this is what I saw:

```
today       votes   daily summary   N/A     Up: 1 Down: 0
2 days ago  votes   daily summary   N/A     Up: 1 Down: 0
2 days ago  comment     added   kernix  @Oliver, saved me a lot of frustration - you rock! :)
May 3       votes   daily summary   N/A     Up: 1 Down: 0
May 3 at 23:36  history     edited  Beau Smith  Added hierarchy, example, numbered steps, and more explanation.
```

Since the edit, it has only got upvotes and *thank you* comments:

> @Oliver, saved me a lot of frustration - *you rock!* :)

It's clear that the answer is still helpful.

Comment: Wow, now you got to choose if the author may keep his original intent or not? Even after it being rolled back by a mod??

Comment: @brasofilo Well, how about if everyone respect the author wishes? Would you agree that I edit your post without an ounce of respect to you? A moderator isn't above the rules, he should respect the author too.

Comment: What's the big issue with someone posting a new answer? Instead of hijacking the biggest upvoted answer?

Comment: @brasofilo Ok, question for you. I improve your answer and you get 100 upvotes afterwards. Should we remove the votes because since you don't accept the edit, you shouldn't either accept the reward that came with it?

Comment: I accept improvements to my posts. Fully rewriting what I wrote it's not my post anymore and I don't want credit for it. Why would I get credit for something I didn't write?

Comment: @brasofilo why you shouldn't? You know that what you are saying makes no sense? Someone gave you a horse and you are looking into the mouth. And anyways, who is anyone to override OP wishes?

Comment: We're not talking about horses, we're talking about authorship of a text.

Comment: @brasofilo It's a proverb https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/don%27t_look_a_gift_horse_in_the_mouth

Comment: @bras the author states his wishes in the question "obviously going to leave it as it is a good edit" the roll back from the mod was in contradiction to those unless they have changed their mind.

Comment: *"What's the big issue with someone posting a new answer? Instead of hijacking the biggest upvoted answer?"* In the short term, posting a new answer buries the useful content, where users who arrive at the question via Google are unlikely to find it. In the long term, assuming that the better answer really does get voted up to the top (which rarely happens as theory says), it steals the thunder from the person who posted the 99% answer. Why shouldn't I flesh out a mostly-complete answer that's already pegged the top of the vote list if I can do so? That makes the site better for everyone. @bra

Comment: @CodyGray I recommend you against using bra as it's both, mine and brasofilo first three letters ;)

Comment: @CodyGray, until now I haven't seen any other input from the post author than this meta question saying he doesn't agree with the edit. A mod rolled the edit back, not sure why Briam is entitled to override both the author and the mod...

Comment: @bras this question doesn't say they disagree with the edit. It specifically says it is a good edit and they intend to leave it. It asks about mechanisms **if** they didn't agree with it.

Comment: @MartinSmith cut brasofilo some slack, the title could trow off some people, which is why I edited it ;)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @rob it was a better fit for the original question title but looks as though Braiam's own edit to the title invalidated their own answer!

Comment: @Rob "You can comment using \@editor to communicate with the editor if necessary but I don't feel that it is at all." How so?