# How to handle an edit that is partially destructive and partially helpful?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

This revision history: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50029981/revisions
notes that Revision 2 has the following impact:

> Improved code formatting.

While it certainly does improve the formatting, it does so in such a way that removes the context for the following:

> I am splitting this file and creating 2 files. One is .header file and other is .body file. Body file will start from "Example_Data" tag. **Now the problem is when the .body file is created the content is creating right from the start of the file without considering the spaces.** Like following:

In essence, the poor formatting is actually required to understand the question.  This type of edit, meant to tidy up code, actually obfuscates the problem entirely.

Now, for this question, I can easily go in and add the spaces back in to keep the original message of the question, but if the edits were more significant and impactful, would this be the same approach, and what, if any, action should I take to inform the editor that he messed up the meaning of the question?

This is similar to another question that involves Suggested Edits, but as the user in question has >2K rep, there is no direct way to provide editing feedback as through the Suggested Edit queue. The options here would be direct rollback or additional edit as basic 2K user privs.

Comment: Am I missing something? There's no such text being removed at all on that post

Comment: @Braiam: the center block quote has all XML indented (by, I presume, the original amount as in the source XML). OP gets that and wants to rid of it. The *edit* removed that exact same whitespace so the question became nonsensical.

Comment: This problem pops up practically every day with Python code. Rather than visible symbols, something like `{..}` (or – yuck – `begin..end` ), Python defines code blocks by *whitespace*. And **nobody** can helpfully edit an OP's post into shape because you do not know if the bad indentation in a post may have *caused* the exact error that an OP was facing.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I was looking for the deleted text.

Comment: "as the user in question has >2K rep, there is no direct way to provide editing feedback" You can @ an editor in the comments. It doesn't autocomplete but I believe they still get notified. Maybe someone who's sure about this can confirm?

Comment: @usr2564301 Oy, Stack Overflow's way of adding code blocks has annoyed me for a long time—you have to add a level of indentation to each line, and invariably every question gets at least one line messed up, necessitating an edit—but I hadn't even considered the carnage that must occur in Python questions. Yikes. Why doesn't SO have something like `{code}` tags so people can just copy/paste their code in verbatim?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka There are `<pre>...</pre>`, `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` (the former ignores leading newlines, but they requires `<` to be `&lt;`, although TIO has the auto format code feature). Also you can highlight them and Ctrl+K. | Then what happens with code containing `{code}`? | It's a limitation of the Markdown engine, not exactly [so].

Comment: I'm curious which part of that edit makes you describe it as "partially helpful".

Comment: @user202729 [Fenced code blocks](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.6/#fenced-code-blocks) have been around for years, yet not on SO.

Comment: @miken32 yep, and here is a [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345774/introduce-autocompletion-for-every-pingable-user) about better ux.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This one is a clear rollback; the OP mentions specifically in the post that the extra spaces in the markup are not only a key part of what he is asking about, they are *exactly* what he is asking about. You'd have to not read the post to miss that.

You should roll the edit back and leave a comment for the editor that removed the spaces indicating--politely--that they should be more careful when editing posts.

Comment: Am I missing something? There's no such text being removed at all on that post.

Comment: @Braiam compare revision 1 and revision 2 https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50029981/revisions - OP above is talking about revision 2 by zx485.

Comment: I don't know what any of you both are seeing. I'm just seeing removing spaces and backticks https://i.stack.imgur.com/50LpB.png

Comment: @Braiam Those removed spaces are the ones Compass is asking about. OP says "Now the problem is when the .body file is created the content is creating right from the start of the file **without considering the spaces**. [...] **But I want to consider the spaces too** so the content in the body file starts from the position it has in the original file(**after 4 spaces or whatever number of spaces** before the Example_Data tag has. I can hardcode for 4 spaces" and so on. It appears OP is talking about the very spaces that zx485 removed from the post.