# Reopen incorrect duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

[Screen reader accessibility for password-like text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55938192) was closed by a [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) gold badge holder as a duplicate of [Force screen reader to read one letter at a time rather than the entire word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37038258).

A user has a valid answer ready (see comments). This answer would not be a valid answer to the duplicate target, demonstrating they they aren't duplicate questions.

Views are very low, so it's not getting enough reopen votes before they expire.

Comment: @gnat then what is [meta-tag:reopen-closed] for if not what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried to ping the gold badge holder who hammered the question? There are also some chat rooms: search for "CSS" in https://chat.stackoverflow.com and ask there. If the gold badger is pingable, ping them there. [Here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign) is a good chat room.

Comment: @double-beep aha, I didn't think of searching for them in chat. You can't ping closers in comments unless they also left a comment.

Comment: FWIW it's now reopen

Comment: Gold badge holders are pingable in comments AFAIK.

Comment: @double-beep I tried and `@` didn't autocomplete their name.

Comment: That doesn't mean they aren't pingable. Editors and gold badge holders only are pingable; their name is autocomplete when they have a comment.

Comment: @double-beep TIL. I'm adding my vote to [Introduce Autocompletion for every pingable user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345774/476716)

Comment: @OrangeDog Not everyone who can be pinged shows up in the `@` list. [Case in point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269863/people-who-bounty-other-peoples-questions-should-be-listed-via-comment-autocompl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is now reopened as this meta post generated sufficient views that agreed with me.

In future, as [double-beep suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385269/reopen-incorrect-duplicate#comment698281_385269), I could try finding the closer in chat if they cannot be pinged in comments.